# Can we safely add pages that Google has already indexed to our XML sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, search-engine-indexing, google-index, xml-sitemap

Most of my website pages are indexed in Google. But in my website's XML sitemap we have fewer pages than the number indexed.

Can we add all those indexed pages in my *sitemap.xml* file? It hurt anything?

Answer (score 1):

Adding pages that are already indexed to your sitemap is not going to cause any problems.

Even if the pages you want to add to your sitemap are not indexed, you should add them to your sitemap anyways. Just be sure these pages don't return 404 when you try to visit them.

Answer (score 1):

The sitemap does not affect rankings, it helps crawl-ability of your site. Is common for Google to index all pages found on your site even if they aren't on the sitemap.

On short: Having a sitemap is not a ranking factor. It just helps Googlebot discover page which otherwise couldn't. It also helps Google index pages faster.

[To get a good understanding read John Muller answer on this post.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Answer (score 1):

You *absolutely should* add all those already-indexed pages to the sitemap, otherwise your sitemap is incomplete. There are no negatives to doing this, only positives.

A sitemap should **always contain the full list of URLs that you want to show up in search**, period. Whether or not the URLs are already indexed in any search engines is irrelevant.

Don't forget that while Google is the biggest player they are not the *only* player. A lot of minor search engines and other web crawlers will benefit from a complete and accurate sitemap.